# How would you create a "private beta" user queue system in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, oauth, npm, twitter-oauth

We're creating a new web app based in Node. As many apps do, we would like to restrict the number of users who sign up, so we can test and scale up smoothly. So, people would sign up (with an email address), and then when a batch of users are released (either manually or automatically), that batch would receive an email that would allow them to sign up.

I've seen this process a number of times on the user side, but have never been involved with building a beta queue system, so I'm not sure the best way to approach this from a architecture / code perspective. Some specific questions might be:

1. What would be the flow for signup from a Node perspective?
2. What might be the underlying data model?
3. For "time-released" or batch releases of users, what might be the best way to manage that or trigger it?
4. Are there are node modules that might help with this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented something like this in a .Net / SQL Server setup.

Basically, the user table had a flag indicating that that user was a beta user and allowed access.

Then I modified the user authentication module to return a different error message indicating that the were signed up but they couldn't access the application yet. This would only show if they successfully authenticated like normal. You could also send them to a different landing page so it doesn't look like they used the wrong credentials.

Next you can provide an admin interface to kick off a script to set the beta flag on a batch of users. This should also trigger some type of notification to let the user know they have access.

For time released options, you could have something else trigger the batch script to set the flags, or have a monitor service that finds any users without access that signed up over X days ago.

I think a lot of this would need to be customized based on your application and when you want to release beta users. There are also some services out there that allow single sign-on and gather analytics about your beta users if you want to see more information without having to roll your own.

Hope this helps. It would be nice to see an actual module you could drop in and configure with your specific database, user model, and authentication / signup process.